# PDO Query return bool(false)

Tags: php

Any idea why this portion of source return `bool(false)` when I `var_dump($row)`?

```
$vote_rank = 0;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(vote_rank) as vote_rank FROM ipaddress_vote_map WHERE image_id = :image_id AND ip_address = :ip_address");
    $query -> bindParam(':image_id', $_GET['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query -> bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    $row = $query->fetch(); 
    $up = "";
    $down = "";

    if(!empty($row[0]["vote_rank"])) {
           $vote_rank = $row[0]["vote_rank"];
           if($vote_rank == -1) {
               $up = "enabled";
               $down = "disabled";
           }
           if($vote_rank == 1) {
               $up = "disabled";
               $down = "enabled";
           }
     }           
     var_dump($row);
```

When I trying to echo the result `$row['vote_rank']` I've got `value='0'` even if is not `0`

Comment: You're not getting an error?

Comment: just a guess but your `$ip_address` is not an `INT` right?

Comment: Isn't ` bool(false)` error?

Comment: @cmorrissey how can be not INT?

Comment: `$rows`, not `$row`?

Comment: it is `$row` .. my mistake but this is not the problem.

Comment: `192.168.1.1  != PDO::PARAM_INT` it is a string `192.168.1.1 == PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: depends, internal representation of an IP can be a number

Comment: Tried both `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` .. still same

Comment: where's the execute() ?

Comment: This is a very very good question. So I forget about `execute()`. Thank's!

Comment: You have the php functions ip2long and long2ip to convert a ipv4 address into a int. Usually its a good idea because the int representation in the database its smaller than the string representation